# VBScript - Read environment variable in if statement

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, environment-variables

What changes must I make for the if statement in my code extract below to work as expected?

```
dim warn, txtfilelocate, txtcontent, file, txtfile, content

call START
sub START
   do while len(txtfilelocate) = 0
   txtfilelocate = inputbox ("Please enter the full path of the text file containing your email content", "CDO Email Sender")
      if isempty(txtfilelocate) then
      wscript.quit()
      end if
   loop
end sub

txtcontent = DQ(txtfilelocate)
wscript.echo txtcontent

set file = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

   if file.fileexists(txtcontent) then
      set txtfile = file.opentextfile(txtcontent, 1)
      content = txtfile.readall
      wscript.echo content
      txtfile.close
      call HELLO
   else
      warn = msgbox(txtcontent & " was not found", 0, "CDO Email Sender")
      call START
   end if

sub HELLO
   wscript.echo "hello"
end sub

function DQ(str)
   DQ = chr(34) & str & chr(34)
end function
```

I suspect it has something to do with expanding environment variables, but as a novice I would appreciate clarification on what I'm doing wrong, and what I should be doing for this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your txtcontent in:

```
if file.fileexists(txtcontent) then
```

contains a quoted file spec. Such quoting is good/necessary when you use .Run or .Exec to shell out, because the shell's parser uses blanks/spaces as separators. The FileSystemObject's method 'know' if an argument is meant as a path/file spec and are not fooled by blanks/spaces, but take spurious quotes literally. So pass txtcontent unquoted to .FileExists.

Evidence:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.FileExists(WScript.ScriptFullName)
>>
-1
>> WScript.Echo goFS.FileExists(qq(WScript.ScriptFullName))
>>
0
>>
```

**Update wrt comment:**

Your script is still a mess. In addition to mixing top level code and Subs/Functions, you simulate a logical loop (repeat until the dumb user has entered a valid file spec) by calling a Sub from different contexts. Put
a line like

```
   WScript.Echo "START called. txtfilelocate is", DQ(txtfilelocate)
```

at the top of Sub START, and you'll see that START **is** entered, but **not** the loop, because txtfilelocate contains the garbage the user entered before.

Comment: Thank you Ekkehard, makes sense now, if I may ask a follow-up question... the else part of the if statement doesn't call the START subroutine why is that?

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard, I failed to see the do while loop requiring txtfilelocate to be in len=0 state to start. I've rewritten the code omitting the do while altogether, it now works fine. Thanks again.